# Find a conformal mapping of the domain $D = \{|z| < 1; |z−\frac 12| > \frac12\}$ to the domain $D′ = \{0 < ℜz < 1\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a conformal mapping of the domain $D = \{|z| < 1; |z−\frac 12| > \frac12\}$ to the domain $D′ = \{0 < ℜz < 1\}$.

Please explain also how do you find this?

Comment: Do you know what the Möbius transformations are?

Comment: No I don't know what are? But trying to find it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the two boundary curves of $D$ are $|z|=1$ and $\left|z-\frac12\right|=\frac12,$ while the two boundary curves of $D'$ are $\Re z=0$ and $\Re z=1.$ Any conformal mapping of $D$ onto $D'$ will map boundary curves onto boundary curves.

Another thing to notice is that the boundary curves of $D$ intersect at $z=1,$ and that the boundary curves of $D'$ intersect at $z=\infty.$ Any conformal mapping of $D$ onto $D'$ should then map $1\mapsto\infty.$

Since all our boundaries are generalized circles (that is, circles or straight lines), then we should consider transformations of the form $$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{z+d},$$ where $ad-b\neq 0.$

Now, since we want $\infty=f(1)=\frac{a+b}{1+d},$ then we need $a\ne -b$ and $d=-1,$ and so our transformation should have the form $$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{z-1}$$ for some $a,b$ with $a\ne-b.$

Next, note that $f(0)=-b.$ Since $f$ must map boundary to boundary, then $-b$ lies either on $\Re z=0$ or on $\Re z=1.$ On the other hand, $f(-1)=\frac{a-b}2$ must also lie on one of these lines, and they can't both lie on the same line since $0,-1$ don't lie on the same boundary curve.

Try picking a nice point on one of those two lines to send $0$ to, solve for $b,$ then find $a$ so that $f(-1)$ lies on the other line. Pick a point in $D$ and see if $f$ sends it to $D'.$ If not, something went wrong. If so, you should try to prove that $f$ does, indeed, map $D$ into and onto $D'$.